# How to add a update profile pic feature in react/firebase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-authentication

I'm working a chat/small social media app, using react and firebase. I working on adding a feature to allow the user to update their name and profile pic. I'm using the firebase "updateProfile" react hook to update everything, so I got the user's user name to update successfully, but when I try to update the user's profile picture nothing happen. I don't even get any errors related to the issue. I tried refreshing the page and checking firebase for any changes, and nothings happening. I tried console logging to see if my "profilepic" useState is storing the image, and it is, I can see the image details and everything in the console.log, but the profile image isn't changing like it does for the user name. Can someone help me with this?

this is the "profilePic" useState

```
  const [profilePic, setProfilePic] = useState(null);
```

this is the function that runs once the user clicks the "Upload Image" button.

```
  const updateProfilePic = async () =>{
    await updateProfile(auth.currentUser, {
      photoURL: profilePic
    }).then(() =>{
  
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
    })
  }
```

this is the JSX. "PulseLoader" is just a react-loader animation I downloaded from "react-spinner"

```
    <img className='change-img' src={firebaseUserInfo?.photoURL || <PulseLoader color={loaderColor}/>} />
    <label className='change-img-btn' onClick={updateProfilePic} for='input-file'>Upload image</label>
    <input type='file' name="myImage" onChange={(e) =>{ console.log(e.target.files[0]); setProfilePic(e.target.files[0])}} id='input-file' />
```

here is a link to my full code.
https://github.com/rsteward117/Chat-App/blob/main/src/componets/customizeProfile.js

Answer (score 1):

Your function `updateProfile` is expecting the `photoURL` field to contain a string URL that is pointing to the image source. Your code seems to be directly passing the file `object` received from the file input.

You need to upload the image to Firebase storage first, and then retrieve the download URL for that image. You can use that URL to update the user profile.

Here is a function to do just that:

```
const uploadImageToStorage = async (imageFile, userId) => {
  const storage = getStorage();
  const storageRef = ref(storage, 'profilePics/' + userId); // Create a reference
  
  // Upload the file
  await uploadBytes(storageRef, imageFile);

  // Get download URL
  const url = await getDownloadURL(storageRef);

  return url;
}
```

And then update your `updateProfilePic` function:

```
const updateProfilePic = async () => {
  try {
    const userId = auth.currentUser.uid;
    const photoURL = await uploadImageToStorage(profilePic, userId);

    await updateProfile(auth.currentUser, {
      photoURL
    });

  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, I have few questions about a few methods that were used like 'getStorage()', 'ref()', and 'getDownloadURL( )' I've never seen them before, do I have to import them somewhere like firebase? I have imported 'getStorage()' from 'firebase/storage'. Where do I get the others from, because they show up as not defined errors on my end.

Comment: @RandySteward Yes, you need to import these at the top of your file. I'm assuming you have installed firebase to your project but if not, do that with - `npm install --save firebase` and then import them at the top of your JS/TS file like so: `import { getStorage, ref, uploadBytes, getDownloadURL } from "firebase/storage";` and 
`import { updateProfile } from "firebase/auth";
`

Comment: whats "ref"?   please elaborate